# Reading a DataFrame from excel and performing actions on it

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have an excel sheet. I want to parse a specific column from it and perform actions to each of cell from that column in python. I am able to parse column using panda as,

```
import pandas
Y = pandas.read_excel("C:\foo\abc.xlsx", sheetname="Prod", 
parse_cols="C", header=1)
print Y
```

I am able to parse columns "C" from sheet Prod using above command. Now, it's printing all the cell's data at a same time. I want to perform action on each cell. can someone advice how to do it?

I want to save each cell data and make some api call by using that data. So i need some kind of for loop which can read a data of single sell at a time and then i can perform api calls by using that cell data and re-run the loop.

Comment: In Pandas we always want to try vectorized approach first, so it might be important to know what kind of action you want to apply to column `C` in order to give you the best answer...

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to save each cell data in a variable and perform api call on each of them. Like i will need to do for loop which will read a single cell at a time and make api call to do something with that data and re-run the loop. if panda is not good for this, what else should i use?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one chained step, using [DataFrame.eval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) method:

Demo - squared column `C`:

```
Y = pandas.read_excel("C:\foo\abc.xlsx", sheetname="Prod", 
                      parse_cols="C", header=1) \
          .eval("C**2", inplace=False)
```

Comment: I updated question. I don't think .eval will work in my situation. can you take a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If your API call does some operation each time that returns a single value (that you want to collect), then you could use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) like this:

```
import pandas as pd


def some_kind_of_function(data_value):
   # Do some API call here that transforms `data_value` into `output_value`

   return output_value


s1 = pd.read_excel("C:\foo\abc.xlsx", sheetname="Prod", parse_cols="C", header=1, squeeze=True)
s2 = s1.map(some_kind_of_function)
```

If your API call is not going to return a value (or nothing that you care about), then you could use [`iteritems`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) like this:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.read_excel("C:\foo\abc.xlsx", sheetname="Prod", parse_cols="C", header=1, squeeze=True)

for (index_value, data_value) in s1.iteritems():
    # Do some API call here that uses `data_value`
```

Note: I've added the parameter `squeeze=True` to the `read_excel` call. This causes the excel data to be stored in a pandas [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) instead of a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).